# Php unknown database?

Tags: php, database, authentication, server, xampp

I'm getting a problem with my Php document. The project is to make a working login/register page
error message-

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'registration' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\server.php on line 11
```

The spelling is correct of the file. Also, it doesn't remember the registrations (I think that's connected to the "unknown database" problem?)

server.php code-

```css
<?php 
 session_start();

 // variable declaration
 $username = "";
 $email    = "";
 $errors = array(); 
 $_SESSION['success'] = "";

 // connect to database
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

 // REGISTER USER
 if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
   array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
   $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
   $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
       VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
   mysqli_query($db, $query);

   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
   header('location: index.php');
  }

 }

 // ... 

 // LOGIN USER
 if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
   $password = md5($password);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
   }else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
   }
  }
 }

?>
```

The file tree

xampp--
  htdocs--
    registration--
     errors.php, index.php, login.php, register.php, server.php, style.css

Comment: Well, **is** there a database called `registration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't created the database called "registration" with the table "users"? As you are on localhost, you may have PHPMyAdmin, which can help you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: See Image]

```
 private $dbName = "forgot_pass_identity";
```

> Note: **type the correct name of DB**